# Scala/Spray/Akka unable to leverage mapRequest

Tags: scala, http-headers, spray, akka-http

I am new to Scala/Spray/AKKA so please excuse this dumb requests.
I have the following Directive and it is being called as the first
logger line ("inside") is showing up in logs.
However, anything inside  mapRequest{} is skipped over.  The logging line  ("headers:") isn't showing up

```
private def directiveToGetHeaders(input: String) : Directive0 = {
    logger.info("inside")
    mapRequest { request =>
    val headList: List[HttpHeader] = request.headers
        logger.info("headers: " + headList.size)
        request
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I did wrong.  My goal is to pull out all the HTTP headers.   Any tip/pointer much appreciated.  Thanks

-v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extractRequest` directive for getting headers.

```
private def directiveToGetHeaders(input: String) : Directive0 = {
    logger.info("inside")
    extractRequest { request =>
      val headList: Seq[HttpHeader] = request.headers
      logger.info("headers: " + headList.size)
      complete(HttpResponse())
    }
}
```